# reset the record selection in PXGrid

Tags: acumatica

We have a view delegate and we are returning custom results according to the filters specified. Once the result is available the user choose any record, say 3rd and uses it. Next time they might change the filter criteria, and the view delegate returns a different set of result.

Here it seems the grid is auto selecting the record in previous position (3).

how can i reset the selection to the first record?

```
    <View>.Current = <FirstRecordINeed>;
    <View>.Cache.ActiveRow = <FirstRecordINeed>;
```

I have tried setting the activeRow/current in view delegate and the filter row updated event. But doesnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

To get ability to affect grid's ActiveRow you should specify property `SyncPositionWithGraph="true"` in the px:PXGrid in aspx.

After that you can set `<View>.Cache.ActiveRow` in the view delegate and it will affect grid.

Comment: What version of the Acumatica do you use?
Can you show me your code?

You can find examples of the usage of that property in the following files:
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\AU\AU203002.aspx(41)
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\AU\AU203002.aspx(214)
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\CS\CS206030.aspx(57)
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\IN\IN204060.aspx(38)
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\SM\SM204520.aspx(584)
\WebSites\Pure\Site\Pages\WZ\WZ202000.aspx(42)

In my case I'm using it like that:
graph(Header_RowUpdated event): Details.Cache.ActiveRow = SelectedDetail.Current;
aspx: <px:PXGrid ... SyncPositionWithGraph="true">

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. After mucking around with "Current" property for an hour I have found ActiveRow which is exactly what I'm after.